# GRUB2 Edits Are Not Taking Effect

Tags: linux, multi-boot, grub, grub2

I have a laptop with UEFI firmware, but had to set the firmware to boot in CSM legacy mode so that I could boot from USB.  I'm multi booting three different linux distros, two of them are Ubuntu.  The distros are all installed on their own Logical Volume.  One of the distros has VirtualBox installed on it, I want it to be my GRUB default, which it currently is not.

I've edited the /etc/default/grub file with sudo as follows:

changed DEFAULT=0 to DEFAULT="saved"
added new line below that... GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"

I then saved the file with :wq!

I then entered the command...  sudo update-grub

With no success after rebooting, I tried...

sudo chmod 744 /boot/grub/grub.cfg
sudo update-grub
sudo chmod 444 /boot/grub/grub.cfg

rebooted, still default boot order hasn't changed.

Installed grub-configuration GUI tool, it reflects all the changes I've made, however still when I reboot the machine, the default boot order hasn't changed.

I've also tried installing a GRUB2 them from GNOMElooks, I used the install script packaged with the download, it hasn't displayed on the GRUB boot splash screen either.

Here's the install.sh file that I executed that came with the GRUB2 theme download:

## !/usr/bin/env bash

GRUB_NAME=""

function compile_grub() {
  echo -e "\e[1m\e[32m==> \e[97mApplying changes...\e[0m"
  ${GRUB_NAME}-mkconfig -o /boot/${GRUB_NAME}/grub.cfg
  echo -e "\e[1m\e[34m  -> \e[97mTheme successfuly applied!"
  echo -e "\e[1m\e[34m  -> \e[97mRestart your PC to check it out."
  sleep 2
}

function update_grub_file() {
  grep -v GRUB_THEME < /etc/default/grub > /tmp/clean_grub
  mv /tmp/clean_grub /etc/default/grub
  echo "GRUB_THEME=/boot/${GRUB_NAME}/themes/Atomic/theme.txt" >> /etc/default/grub
}

function copy_atomic_files() {
  echo -e "\e[1m\e[32m==> \e[97mDownloading files...\e[0m"
  git clone https://github.com/lfelipe1501/Atomic-GRUB2-Theme /tmp/Atomic-GRUB2-Theme
  echo -e "\e[1m\e[32m==> \e[97mCopying files...\e[0m"
  cp -rf /tmp/Atomic-GRUB2-Theme/Atomic /boot/${GRUB_NAME}/themes/
}

function main() {

# Check user is root
  if [ $UID == 0 ]; then
    echo "Yes, You are root!"
  else
    echo "No, You must be root!"
    exit 1
  fi

# Check which grub
  if [ -d "/boot/grub" ]; then
      GRUB_NAME="grub"
  else
      GRUB_NAME="grub2"
  fi
  copy_atomic_files

echo -e "\e[1m\e[97m  You must set the theme in your GRUB config file,"
  while : ;do
    if [ "$answer" = "g" ];then
      echo -e "\e[1m\e[97m  You didn't give a valid option, try again."
    else
      read -p "  Would you like to do it now? [y/n] " -t 10 answer
      echo -e "\e[0m"
      if [ "$answer" = "y" ];then
    # backup old grub file
    cp /etc/default/grub /tmp/grub$(date '+%m-%d-%y_%H:%M:%S')
    update_grub_file
        compile_grub
    break
      elif [ "$answer" = "n" ];then
        break
      fi
      let answer=g
    fi
  done

}

main "$@"
exit 0

Comment: * had to set the firmware to boot in CSM legacy mode so that I could boot from USB* Sorry, no, absolutely not. If you had to do that then you burned the USB in a wrong way. If you used Rufus (Windows) with the default options then it'll boot in Legacy/BIOS only. You need to select GPT/UEFI. But also you want to install a multi-boot in the same mode, always. And if your system is UEFI then you also want to install all in such mode which, by the way, makes multi-booting a LOT easier.

Comment: Thanks for your input Gabriela.  I used etcher to reformat and write to the USB.  If I selected GPT/UEFI scheme for writing to the USB, and then try to use that USB to boot by first putting my firmware in EFI mode, my laptop just hangs as soon as I exit "BIOS/EFI" and try to start booting from the USB.  I actually tried Rufus as well, using GPT/UEFI scheme option for reformatting and writing the image to the USB with the same results.  Only when I reformatted the USB using CSM and modified my laptop's "BIOS/EFI" settings to boot in CSM/legacy mode was I able to boot from USB.

Comment: your q need basic post editing, it can be more readable!

Answer (score 0):

GRUB has a number of components.  Part is located where the laptop firmware starts the boot process, and that points to the rest.  Each Linux distro you installed has its own copy of GRUB with settings like what you edited.  At installation, the distro replaces the portion that starts the process with its own segment that points to its own settings.

So the last distro you installed is the one that's actually controlling things.  If you want to change the GRUB settings, you need to do it in the last distro you installed, or run `grub-install` in a distro installed earlier to make it the one that is started.  Discussion in this post may be helpful: [update-grub vs. grub-install?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/465207/85417)